# How do I bind data to the attributes of a progress bar?

Tags: android

I'm building an app that has a ListActivity and the view for each item has a progress bar. I've been able to bind my data to the TextView, but I can't seem to figure out how to bind it to the max and progress of the ProgressBar.

This is a simplified version of my view:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
<TextView android:id="@+id/text1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>
<ProgressBar android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/text1"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

and I'm using the same method as the Notepad tutorials to put my data into the views:

```
String[] from = new String[]{MyDbAdapter.KEY_AMOUNT};
int[] to = new int[]{R.id.text1};
SimpleCursorAdapter list_adapter = 
    new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.item_row, myCursor, from, to);
setListAdapter(list_adapter);
```

Adding MyDbAdapter.KEY_AMOUNT and R.id.progress_bar to the arrays throws an exception (java.lang.IllegalStateException: android.widget.ProgressBar is not a  view that can be bounds by this SimpleCursorAdapter). Is there some kind of @... that I need to use for max and progress to make this work?

Answer (score 3):

You have to create a new class that implements `SimpleCursorAdapter`.`ViewBinder` and override the `setViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor, int columnIndex)` method to implement what you want your progress bar to do with the returned cursor data.

Then you call `list_adapter.setViewBinder( ViewBinder)` and pass your new `ViewBinder` object in there.

Answer (score 2):

You will probably need to override `bindView()` (and, possibly, `newView()`) and do the binding "by hand" in Java code. `SimpleCursorAdapter` knows how to handle `TextView` and children automatically, but everything else needs help.

Comment: I had the very same problem just now, and it turned out that just setting a custom class that implements SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder did the work, no need to override bindView. Of course, I'm using android.support.v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter, so I am not sure if that makes a difference.

Comment: @Bilthon can you please be kind enough and add an answer with the sample code how you did it with the progress bar? I tried ViewBinder but it won't allow me to cast the `View view` parameter to `ProgressBar` type.